# I still didn't fall in love or I didn't still fall in love?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

What is the correct structure to refer to something that's true up to the present moment?

1. > I **still** didn't fall in love
2. > I didn't **still** fall in love

Answer (score 2):

Your #1 means something like this: "Even after an event that could have made me fall in love, I didn't." That's a fairly common thing someone might say.

Your #2 is a lot less common, but would mean something more like this: "I would have been expected to fall in love, like I had previously, but I didn't this time." This isn't very likely, but if that's what you want to say, something closer to "I didn't keep falling in love" or "I didn't fall in love that time" would be much clearer, even though they don't express all the little nuances.

But it looks like you actually want to say neither of those. Instead, "I still haven't fallen in love" means that you have continued without love and are still in that state.

Comment: By the way, is is not better to use present perfect tense in this case? 
"I have still not fallen in love" (or something like that)

Comment: @Assiduous: That depends entirely on whether you're recounting past events, or explaining up to the present moment. You might be telling a story about how, twenty years ago, a girl did such-and-so, but you still didn't fall in love.... In such a case, you may actually have married her later, or fell in love with someone else, or might be lonely to this day.

Comment: I'm talking about this moment